# Resetting Application Scope on ColdFusion cluster

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Is there a way to reset the Application, via onApplicationStart, and ensure that all the servers in the cluster have their application restarted?

For example, in the current code, DSN is set in request.
I would like to push it to application scope, but if there is a change that needs to be made, I would like to make sure it is propagated to all the servers in the cluster without starting and stopping CF services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One suggestion is to have a date-stamped file in your project that each server can read.

Get CF to save the date into the application on start-up and compare what it has against that file in each onRequestStart().

If the date ever changes then CF runs the onApplicationStart() of that server.

We use that technique with our ANT scripts, so as we deploy to each server ANT timestamps the file and the next person to hit our application causes the application reset.

Cheers,
James

Comment: Do you see any performance issues with having to do an additional cffile read on every request?

Comment: Yeah that's a con to the approach but you can take the edge off things by dropping down to Java and using java.io.File. The main benefits are you can apply this to single / clustered environments without too much hassle, you don't have to rely on URL reinitialising to reset things and your server code remains isolated to whatever server is running it. Adobe do need to get their fingers out though and make managing cluster code a lot easier. Something I've asked for for the past 3 versions has been application scope support across a cluster. Can't see it happening soon though :-(

Comment: Just had a thought actually - you've got onRequestEnd as well. So you could do the file check after a request has finished. That at least menas that the user trigger the application reload at least gets their results before the process kicks off. Might be more efficient :-)

Answer (score 3):

We have our applications set up to reset their scopes via URL variable. So you could use code like this to restart the applications on all servers in your cluster via http through a page in your admin:

```
<cfset serverList = "Server1.domain.com,Server2.domain.com" />
<cfset threadList = "" />
<cfloop list="#serverList#" index="currentServer">
    <cfset threadList = ListAppend(threadList, "thread#currentServer#") />
    <cfthread
        action="run"
        name="thread#currentServer#"
        url="http://#currentServer#?URLToResetScope"
        key="#currentIndex#"
    >
        <cfhttp method="get" url="#Attributes.URL#" result="thread.cfhttp" />
    </cfthread>

</cfloop>
<cfthread action="join" name="#threadList#" timeout="120000" />
<cfloop list="#threadList#" index="currentThread">
    <cfset Results &= currenthThread & ": " & threadresult.cfhttp />
</cfloop>
```

What we're doing is taking a list of servers, then looping through that list, and with cfthread, passing off a request to each server to reset it's own scope. Then, we join all those threads together, and loop through them to get the results of each request. Then we can display those results in the admin, to make sure that all servers in the cluster got updated correctly. If there is any server that *didn't* get updated correctly, we can then go reset that server individually.

Dan

Comment: That won't necessarily work if you're servers are on round robin. In that setup sessions are allocated to a specific server depending on the way you've told it to manage things (i.e. 50% / 50% ).

Comment: ... so you can't guarantee that this will work for every cluster environment and that every server will get their request. You can do a bit of hacking with sessionID on the HTTP, each server has a unique id so you can force the request onto a specific server, but generally we've found this way to be a headache to manage and "bending the rules" on how things should work.

Comment: We use Dan's approach as well and get around the problem James brings up by using each server's internal IP address. This way we by-pass load balancing altogether.

Comment: We had problems with this as well sadly. I can't remember the specifics but it came down to the fact that CF has to eventually get the request - IP or Domain - and that's where the "ping-pong" problems of round robin gave us the headache.

Comment: I have my domains set up to go through www.domain.com for round robin, and I have DNS entries set up for server1.domain.com and server2.domain.com (or I use internal IPs) to make sure that I hit the server I want to hit, and that I'm not being put through the cluster round robin.

Comment: Hi Dan, this is a great answer but I am running into cluster problems with this approach.  And it is a fairly large cluster.